# How to run a function after debounce in ng-model-options in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

if i have an input field like the one below;

```
   <input type="text" name="myName" class="form-control" ng-model="Info.personName" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
```

How can i run a function in angular.js to save the value that the user has provided in the input field

Comment: when you say "save the value", do you mean "store the value in `Info.personName`" or do you mean "send `Info.personName` to the server"?

Comment: i want to make an ajax call and save the input value to a database

Comment: But am wondering how i can capture that value from that field as most examples i see only show binding to another element. Take updating a user profile forexample, am trying to avoid having submit buttons but rather a debouce action that would be like set timeout in vanilla javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is actually part of the magic of AngularJs bindings and `ng-model-options`.

With `ng-model-options` `debounce`, AngularJs does not "change" the value of the model until the debounce time has elapsed.  Other AngularJs Directives, such as `ng-change`, monitor the change to the model, not the change to the input element.  Therefore, `ng-change` can be used to call a function, and that function will not trigger until the debounce has elapsed.

**Example:** (Changed to `2000ms` to show an obvious delay)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Info = {};

  $scope.changeFunction = function() {
    console.log('change called');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" name="myName" ng-change="changeFunction()" class="form-control" ng-model="Info.personName" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }" />
</body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CkUmqzxOjHXrKKHJKMez?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Claies, this actually does help quite alot